# PowerShell matching strings with Regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm working on a script to move tv shows in to their corresponding folder on my drive.  I'm having issues matching shows to their folders. This is the snippet of code I'm having a problem with:

```
#Remove all non-alphanumeric characters from the name
$newname = $Episode.Name -replace '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]', ' '  

#Split the name at S01E01 and store the showname in a variable (Text before S01E01) 
$ShowName = [regex]::Split($newname, 'S*(\d{1,2})(x|E)')[0]

#Match and get the destination folder where the names are similar
################## THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS #######################
$DestDir = Gci -Path $DestinationRoot | Where { $ShowName -like "*$($_.Name)*" } | foreach {$_.Name }
```

For example, a show named "Doctor Who 2005 S02E02 Tooth and Claw.mp4" is not returning a similar folder, which is named "DoctorWho".

Question(s):
Who can I modify the $DestDir so that I can match the names?  Is there a better way of doing this?

**Working Code:**

```
# Extract the name of the show (text before SxxExx)
$ShowName = [regex]::Split($Episode.Basename, '.(\d{1,3})(X|x|E|e)(\d{1,3})')[0]

# Assumption: There is a folder in TV shows directory that is named correctly, and the input file is named correctly
# Try to match by stripping all non-Alphabet characters from both names and check if the folder name contains the file name
$Folder = gci -Path $DestinationRoot | 
          Where {$_.PSisContainer -and `
          (($_.Name -replace '[^A-Za-z]','') -match ($ShowName -replace '[^A-Za-z]','')) } |
          select -ExpandProperty fullname
```

Some sample output from testing:

```
Input file name:   Arrow S01E02.mp4
Show name:         Arrow 
Matching folder:   C:\Users\Public\Videos\TV Shows\Arrow
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Input file name:   Big Bang Theory S3E03.avi
Show name:         Big Bang Theory 
Matching folder:   C:\Users\Public\Videos\TV Shows\The Big Bang Theory
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Input file name:   Doctor Who S08E03.mp4
Show name:         Doctor Who 
Matching folder:   C:\Users\Public\Videos\TV Shows\Doctor Who (2005)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Input file name:   GameOfThronesS01E01.mp4
Show name:         GameOfThrones
Matching folder:   C:\Users\Public\Videos\TV Shows\Game Of Thrones
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Forgive me for stating the obvious, but why don't you just make sure the folders match the show names, that is, rename "DoctorWho" to "Doctor Who 2005"? PowerShell doesn't know what your idea of "similar" is, you'd have to spell out each individual case. One thing you can do is add `.Trim()` so spaces at the beginning and end are removed, but you'll have to spell out further transformations explicitly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That would work in my case.  However, I had planned on sharing this with others once I've completed.  I'm not sure what they setups are like, so I was trying to make it as universal as possible.

Comment: Well, you can do stuff like "strip out all the spaces and trailing numbers in both show name and folder names and start matching", but it seems probable that no matter what you do, someone will complain that it doesn't work properly. At least the simple algorithms have the benefit that people can understand what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same method as you to figure out what the show name is based on your suggestion. With `Doctor Who 2005 S02E02 Tooth and Claw.mp4`

```
$showName = $Episode -replace '[^0-9a-zA-Z ]'
$showName = ($showName -split ('S*(\d{1,2})(x|E)'))[0]
$showName = $showName -replace "\d"
```

I added the line `$showName = $showName -replace "\d"` to account for the year in the season. There is a caveat with this if the show contains a number in the middle of it but should work for most. Continuing to the `$DestDir` determination. Part of the issue is you have your `Where` comparison backwards. You want to see if the show name is part of the potential folder, not the other way around. Also since the potential folder could contain spaces the comaparison should also contain that assumption.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationRoot -Directory  | Where-Object { ($_.name -replace " ") -like "*$($showName)*"}
```

I would go on to use a [`Choice`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx) selection to have the user confirm the folder since it is possible to have multiple matches. I would like to point out that it might be hard to account for all naming conventions and variances but what you have is a good start.

Comment: I wound up doing something similar to what you have suggested.  I did a contains, rather than a like.  As for the choice, I've decided the script will just email the user letting them know that there are files that didn't match, which will require manual intervention.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kevin_ `-contains` only works for arrays. In a `where-object` you will not be using an array. FYI

Comment: Whoops, meant to say -match.